# Motivo da demora do processo e configuração do hibernate (persistence)

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, jpa-2.0

Estou montando um servidor WS com Java, e estou vendo algumas problemas, como o login via POSTMAN, está demorando entre 6000 a 7500 ms para responder, sendo o que ele realmente faz, é de em torno 50 ms.
Após conseguir configurar o log4, a maior parte da demora está em:  
`org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect` até  `org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper`

 e também 
`INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect` até `org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryRegistry`. 
Segue abaixo todo o stack do log:

```
018-01-31 14:21:38 INFO  org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper     - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: persistence_unit_meudb
    ...]
2018-01-31 14:21:38 WARN  org.hibernate.orm.connections     - HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
2018-01-31 14:21:38 INFO  org.hibernate.orm.connections     - HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/meudb]
2018-01-31 14:21:38 INFO  org.hibernate.orm.connections     - HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
2018-01-31 14:21:38 INFO  org.hibernate.orm.connections     - HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
2018-01-31 14:21:38 INFO  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl     - HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
2018-01-31 14:21:38 INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect     - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2018-01-31 14:21:42 INFO  org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper     - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: persistence_unit_meudb
    ...]
2018-01-31 14:21:42 WARN  org.hibernate.orm.connections     - HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
2018-01-31 14:21:42 INFO  org.hibernate.orm.connections     - HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/meudb]
2018-01-31 14:21:42 INFO  org.hibernate.orm.connections     - HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
2018-01-31 14:21:42 INFO  org.hibernate.orm.connections     - HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
2018-01-31 14:21:42 INFO  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl     - HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
2018-01-31 14:21:42 INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect     - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2018-01-31 14:21:45 WARN  org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryRegistry     - HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (persistence_unit_meudb) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'
Antes do Try: 2018-01-31 14:21:45.345
2018-01-31 14:21:45 INFO  org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator     - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: 
    select
        [ Campos ]
    from
        tbusuario usuario0_ 
    where
        usuario0_.login=? 
Antes do Return: 2018-01-31 14:21:45.387
2018-01-31 14:21:45 INFO  org.hibernate.orm.connections     - HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/meudb]
2018-01-31 14:21:45 INFO  org.hibernate.orm.connections     - HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/meudb]
Antes do Return: 2018-01-31 14:21:45.389
```

Gostaria de saber se há alguma configuração a se fazer no persistence ou biblioteca que deixe esse processo mais rápido.

Segue o meu persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
                                http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" 
             version="2.0" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

   <persistence-unit name="persistence_unit_meudb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/meudb"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>

         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Tomcat, já resolvi um dos problemas que é de criar mais de 1 conexão por requisição, foi criando um classe que cria as conexões e passa esses dados para os respectivos daos.

Comment: Oi Felipe, então, esse tipo de soluções caseiras geralmente são o gargalo. Você pode configurar o seu datasource diretamente no Tomcat. Dessa forma o próprio Tomcat mantém um *connection Pools* com conexões abertas em *background*. Documentação:  https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html . JTA ou anotações declarativas do Spring também ajudam bastante no desenvolvimento e administração correta de transações.

Comment: Dei uma olhada na documentação que me mandou, e procurei outros artigos, mas não entendi como eu poderia aplicar o Datasource em minha aplicação. Ps: uso Maven para gerenciamento das dependecias.

Answer (score 1):

Em produção a recomendação é não utilziar essas linhas abaixo, use apenas para efeitos de teste caso contrário toda vez que o serviço for inciado será analisados alterações em seu modelo, e os scripts serão exibidos no log

```
 <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
 <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>

 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

Comment: Então devo tirar o show_sql, e format_sql para não aparecerem nos logs, e devo também tirar o hbm2dll ? Mas e caso, haja alteração no Modelo, mas foi esquecido de passar para o banco ?

Comment: Existem algumas estrategias, mas como eu disse na resposta em produção não se recomenda essas opções. Você pode gerar o script pra se aplicar em produção ou apontar o código de desenvolvimento para  produção para que as alterações sejam realizadas.